# iframe Allowfullscreen not working in ie11 , works for youtube video not for other site src

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

Here are two lines of HTML code:

My website url (doesn’t work in IE)

```
<iframe style="box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; margin: 20px; float: right;" mce_style="box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; margin: 20px; float: right;" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xDMP3i36naA" mce_src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xDMP3i36naA" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="230" width="400" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

YouTube (does work in IE)

```
<iframe style="box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; margin: 20px; float: right;" mce_style="box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; margin: 20px; float: right;" src="http://zenarate.com/index.php?r=site/embeddVideos&amp;id=NzIxOA%3D%3D" mce_src="http://zenarate.com/index.php?r=site/embeddVideos&amp;id=NzIxOA%3D%3D" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="230" width="400" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The YouTube video link works fine but the Mysite video link will not go to full screen in Internet Explorer 11 (although both work fine in FireFox and Chrome).

How can I resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ie11 doesnt allow us to use allowfullscreen. I used flash player for it.