# Embedding Box widget (IFrame) in IE does not work, but works in Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, box, cewp

I have a Box folder and I am trying to embed the folder in my SharePoint site using content editor webpart. I copy the iframe code on my site page I add content editor webpart (CEWP). In the CEWP I add my iframe code which looks something like this.

`<iframe src="https://<ORGANIZATION>.app.box.com/embed/s/<Alphanumeric string of 32 chars>" width="500" height="400" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>`

This works in Chrome. In IE, it only shows sign in page but the sign in does not work. In the debugger there's no error. I am using IE 11.

What can be the issue over here?

Comment: Looks like issue with IE. Try and add the box site(`*.box.com`) in the trusted zone and check. To add it to trusted sites, check this [link](https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/how-add-trusted-sites-internet-explorer)

Comment: Simply, IE sucks! Use Chrome :-)

Comment: did you try the url directly in ie without using an iframe ?

Comment: Looks like IE has some problems with allowfullscreen in iframe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148124/iframe-allowfullscreen-not-working-in-ie11-works-for-youtube-video-not-for-oth

Comment: did you try adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> to the header? IE sometimes open pages in old IE modes, this forces it to use the latest one available in the client.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like P3P problem.
If you have php you can try:

```
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi NAV OUR STP IND DEM"');
```

Or the equivalent in your serverside language.